# Como instalar a bibliteca scipy no python?

Tags: python-2.7, scipy

Eu tentei instalar usando o programa WinPython, mas ao importar a biblioteca ocorreu um erro:

">>> from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
    from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
">>>ImportError: No module named scipy.optimize"

Answer (score 1):

Recomendo a utilização da plataforma Anaconda:

https://www.continuum.io/downloads

O Anaconda vem com os pacotes científicos 'base',tais como: matplotlib, pandas, scipy e numpy. Todos os pacotes e o ambiente ficam restritos a uma única pasta, facilitando assim a desinstalação e o Anaconda vem também com o Jupyter (antigo ipython notebook) e a IDE Spyder.

Answer (score 0):

Tenta utilizar isto:
https://code.google.com/p/winpython/

Vem com o Scipy ja instalado

Answer (score 0):

Pela linha de comando do seu sistema operacional, se você possuir o pip instalado:

```
pip install scipy
```

Mais sobre o pip em https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip